# Beginner Functions in C

Tags: c, function, clang

My program calculates the sum, difference, quotient, and product of two numbers provided by the user. In my code, I am using print statements in the *main* function to supply this information to the user, however, I am trying to figure out a way to use a function that I can simply call in order to print all of the results of the process, to the user. I'm new to functions so the help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much.

```
//declare functions
int firstuserinput(void);
int seconduserinput(void);
int calcSum(int, int);
int calcProduct(int, int);
int calcDifference(int, int);
int calcQuotient(int, int);

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int sum, product, difference, quotient, num1, num2;
    num1=firstuserinput();
    num2=seconduserinput();

    sum = calcSum(num1, num2);
    product = calcProduct(num1, num2); 
    difference = calcDifference(num1, num2);
    quotient = calcQuotient(num1, num2);

    printf("\nThe sum of the two numbers: %d\n", sum );
    printf("The product of the two numbers: %d\n", product);
    printf("The difference of the two numbers: %d\n", difference);
    printf("The quotient of the two numbers: %d", quotient);    

}
//Input Functions
int firstuserinput()
{
    int num1; 
    printf("Please enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    return num1;   
}

int seconduserinput()
{
    int num2;
    printf("Please enter another number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    return num2; 
}
//Process functions
int calcSum(int x, int y)
{
    return x+y;


}

int calcProduct(int x, int y)
{
    return x*y;


}

int calcDifference(int x, int y)
{
    return x-y;


}

int calcQuotient(int x, int y)
{
    return x/y; 


}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to take the `printf` statements at the bottom of the code and make a function that does that instead?

Comment: Yes, instead of the printf statements being in main, I want to know how to take those statements and put them into a single function.

Comment: I hope you can see that there is no need for `firstuserinput()` *and* `seconduserinput()` because they do exactly the same thing. That is the beauty of a function: to generalise an operation. You could replace both of them with a similar `intuserinput()` function. But, I don't see why you need a function to print all the results. Also be careful of `return x/y;` when `y == 0`.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to be able to just put all of the input into one function, but I don't know how to then get that function to work in main?

Answer (score 2):

Create a function that takes your results and prints it:

```
void printResults(int sum, int product, int difference, int quotient) {
    printf("\nThe sum of the two numbers: %d\n", sum );
    printf("The product of the two numbers: %d\n", product);
    printf("The difference of the two numbers: %d\n", difference);
    printf("The quotient of the two numbers: %d", quotient);
}
```

In main:

```
   ...
    printResults(sum, product, difference, quotient);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend this function to other operators:

```
void printResult(char operator, int result) {
char *op;
switch(operator)
{
case '+':
op="Sum";
break;
case '-':
op="difference";
break;
case '*':
op="multiplication";
break;
case '/':
op="division";
break;
}
printf("The %s of the two numbers: %d",op, result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best thing you could do for yourself is to learn to pseudocode. As in, don't write any actual application code at first. Instead, sit down and write down the behaviors of the program. An example for your current program would be:

> - **Accept input** for first number
> - **Accept input** for second number
> - **Calculate** sum
> - **Calculate** product
> - **Calculate** difference
> - **Calculate** quotient
> - **Print** Results

Now, what you want to do is isolate the verbs. Since functions are by definition actions to be performed by the code, and a verb in plain English is an action, writing down in plain English what you want the program to do and singling out the verbs is a great way to identify candidates for functions. In this case, we have Accept Input, Calculate, and Print. Next, you want to generalize them as much as possible, isolate the parts that change between the different versions of the action, and make those parts that change into variables, all while keeping in mind the limitations of the language you're using.

For example, C (and most modern languages) can only return a single value. Creating a `Calculate` function that does all of the operations at once is far from impossible, but because C doesn't return multiple values from a function, you'd have to either define a structure that holds four integers or pass pointers to the integers instead of the values so that you can change the actual numbers and not just a copy of them. I'll detail the function version here. The function definition would look like this: `Calculate(int lvalue, int rvalue, int *sum, int *product, int *difference, int *quotient)`. To understand this, you need to know that when you call a function, the parameters you pass in are *passed by value* by default. What this means is that you send *copies* of the data to the function to operate on. When you pass a *pointer* to data using the `*` symbol, you instead send the function the ***location*** of the data in memory, allowing you to (among other things) modify the value directly instead of using a copy of the data. Which means you can assign a value to that location in memory by doing something like `*sum = lvalue + rvalue` in your function. This is a more advanced option due to the immense power - and numerous nuances - of pointers, but one that you should seriously consider researching. The more you really want to learn, the more you will discover. The most exciting thing about programming is that the learning never stops. You can dive as deep as your heart desires.

That said, let's look at the remaining - and far simpler - verbs. Accept input - specifically, accept numerical input - can be done in two ways. Using pointers, you can make a function that returns `void` and accepts an `int*` instead of just `int`. In the function, you would read user input (and hopefully check it for errors and make sure it's actually a number) and assign it to the `int*` in one go. If you can master pointers, you'll make your life much easier, both in class and beyond. Things like making sure that the pointers point to a value come to mind. The function definition would look like `void AcceptInput(int *value)` and your first two lines would look more like this:

> ```
> AcceptInput(&num1);
> AcceptInput(&num2);
> ```

A simpler version of an `AcceptInput` function would probably look more like what you have now. Read the input, check to make sure it's a valid number, and return the result. Because you are only returning a single value, the simpler code should be chosen unless you have a good reason for choosing otherwise. In almost every case, I'd personally choose this option. Your function definition would look like this: `int AcceptInput();` and your first lines of code would change ever so slightly:

> ```
> num1 = AcceptInput();
> num2 = AcceptInput();
> ```

As an aside, I'd also take this moment to point something else out. I would personally avoid using meaningless names for variables. What on earth is `num1`? What does that mean? Kick this practice immediately. Always name your variables something that makes it obvious just by looking at it what it is supposed to do or be. Having an entire program of meaningless variable names is a great way to make debugging much harder than it has to be, and to frustrate people who have to maintain your code after they inherit it. This is a stylistic suggestion, mind you, but it's something that both in my college life and in my professional life makes going back and looking at old code much less painful.

The last verb is `Print`. What are we printing? Results. I could have separated the different individual types of results (quotient, difference, etc) but we'd still end up in the same place: they're all printing a type of result, and we'd have simplified them to "print results" in the end anyway. So now what? Well, let's define the function. It won't return anything. And it needs to know the results it is printing. so the definition would look something like `void PrintResults(int sum, int product, int difference, int quotient);`. Notice how there aren't any `*`s this time; we only need the values. We aren't changing anything, so passing copies of the values instead of the memory locations is more than sufficient.

This answer is really long, and some of it might be a bit jumbled (I just woke up) but I sincerely hope my answer teaches you things and encourages you to ask more questions, dive deeper, and research more about C. C is the progenitor of most modern languages; having a solid understanding of it (and C++ afterwards) will give you the building blocks necessary to quickly pick up most other languages. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14

int main()
{
    int  a,b,c,d;
    printf("The first integer is:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("The second integer is:");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    c=add(a,b);
    d=sub(a,b);
    printf("The sum of a and b is %d and the difference is %d",c,d);
}
    int add (int a,int b)

    {

       return (a+b);
    }
    int sub (int a,int b)

    {

       return(a-b);
    }
```